# Why are SRV records static in one Windows domain, and dynamic in another windows domain?

Tags: active-directory

So, I noticed today that SRV records under `_sites.mydomain.com` for example are listed as static. Those are records for `_gc`, `_kerberos`, `_ldap`, etc.

But, my understanding is that NETLOGON creates these records and refreshes them automatically and I wouldn't expect them to show as static entries. I checked an equivalent domain at another organization and all of the equivalent entries are timestamped and do not say static.

However, on the domain where the entries are static, if I delete one of them, and restart the netlogon service for the server entry I removed, the entry is recreated automatically as expected - but again, it is static.

Why are these entries listed as static at one site, and timestamped (dynamic) at another site?